# Is it safe to point cardano-wallet at Daedalus "wallets" directory?

Tags: daedalus, cardano-cli, wallet

I'm running an instance of `cardano-wallet` which is already pointed at my Daedalus node socket. Would it be safe/possible to point to the `wallets` directory of Deadalus via the `--database` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried a couple times now and it seems this is not possible. It does not corrupt Daedalus's database but throws errors instead.

```
Unexpected error following the chain:
user error (restoreBlocks: given chain isn't a valid continuation.
Wallet is at: [...] but the given chain continues starting from: [...])
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have your recovery phrase backed up in a secure place, you can always restore your wallet in case the Daedolus directory gets corrupted. So there's no problem with using `cardano-wallet` with your Daedolus files.